# React npm start show something in new version

Tags: reactjs

I found something new output in new version, I don't know what its name.

There are picture below, green text.

After `npm start`

**Previous version only show**

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.108:3000
Note that the development build is not optimized.

To create a production build, use npm run build.

---

**New Version show extra thing**

assets by chunk 1.5 MiB (name: main)

asset static/js/bundle.js 1.5 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset

asset main.aa0b3f79a143f8b72953.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]

asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]

webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 444 ms

---

[image]

How can I close extra thing, I think that is useful information.

But I do not like it, if I don't need that.

Any way to close it or show it?

Comment: Use `--display` and choose which level of log output you expect.

Comment: ```--display: Select display preset
[string] [choices: "", "verbose", "detailed", "normal", "minimal", "errors-only", "none"]```

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy tried npm start --display: "minimal"  but didn't work.

Comment: Even I am facing a similar thing. Any solution so far ?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue too, has anyone figured out what's happening here?

This is what I see in the terminal after the Local/On Your Network: `asset static/js/bundle.js 1.46 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.35 MiB [cached] 101 modules
runtime modules 28.1 KiB 13 modules
javascript modules 3.42 KiB
  ./src/index.js 1.83 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/App.js 1.59 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.66.0 compiled successfully in 5304 ms`

Comment: Does anyone Find the Solution?

Answer (score 3):

That's because of ***react-scripts@5.0.0***

If you want to remove that you have to downgrade react-scripts@5.0.0 to react-scripts@4.0.3

For Install react-scripts@4.0.3

```
npm remove react-scripts
npm install react-scripts@4.0.3
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `create-react-app` for the project and it uses `react-scripts` to build and run the web app.

The green outputs are from `webpack` bundling information.
Could you share the `npm start` command in more details if you don't mind.

`react-scripts` changelog didn't mention about that and not sure if it's actual bug from `react-scripts` or not.

Answer (score -1):

Well after a lot of debugging, my suspicion is that there are some webpack compatibility issues with what the create-react-app template implements in its newest versions. I hope that this helps anyone struggling with this issue:

## ❌  What is causing the error:

In my package.json file, I was using these packages, which gave the super annoying terminal output described above.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

## ✅ A fix that works for me:

This is the downgraded packages that removed his terminal output noted above. My assumption is that this is a react-scripts issue, but I did update the other dependencies as well to be sure.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
  },
```

Hopefully this helps anyone struggling with this too!

Comment: No, It does not work for me. Testing libraries are not associated with Build process. So there is no chance that removing test libraries will fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @HassanAjaz — did you see I downgraded the react, react-dom, and react-scripts packages (yes I technically removed the test libraries, but was more trying to highlight the downgrading of the packages)? There is a bit of a webpack incompatibility issue w/ the newest version of react/react-scripts w/ create-react-app....did you downgrade your packages to this?